# How to use count with CASE condition in a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, case

```
SELECT
COUNT(
 CASE WHEN ( DATE(igs.start_date) >= DATE('2020-05-01') 
           AND DATE(igs.start_date) <= DATE('2020-05-31') 
      THEN igs.id 
      ELSE 0
 END
) AS totalSessions
FROM
`ignite_session` igs
```

My requirement is I want session count of a particular month. From above query, I am getting the wrong count. When I checked with the below query it is 0.

```
 SELECT
      COUNT(id)
 FROM
      ignite_session igs
 WHERE
      DATE(igs.start_date) >= DATE('2020-05-01') 
      AND DATE(igs.start_date) <= DATE('2020-05-31')
```

The First Query is small part of complex query. I do not want to use date condition in where statement.
Please help me with this CASE STATEMENT query. `totalSessions` should return 0.

Comment: dates don't need to be wrapped in a `DATE` function

Comment: Why don't you want to use the `date` in the where cluase? Is the right result not what you where after?

Comment: *From above query, I am getting the wrong count.* Of course. `COUNT(expression)` counts the amount of expression values which are not NULL. Both CASE altertnatives are not NULL (igs.id - because it seems to be PK, zero - is a constant). So your COUNT(CASE ...) is a common COUNT(*). Use `SUM(expression)` instead, without CASE: `SUM(DATE(igs.start_date) BETWEEN '2020-05-01' AND '2020-05-31')`.

Comment: Don't forget to flag your question as solved by picking an answer if it fix your problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `NULL` in your else case.

like :

```
SELECT
COUNT(
    CASE WHEN (DATE(igs.start_date) >= DATE('2020-05-01') 
        AND DATE(igs.start_date) <= DATE('2020-05-31'))
    THEN igs.id 
    ELSE NULL
    END
) AS totalSessions
FROM
`ignite_session` igs
```

---

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ef866/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t1
    (`c1` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO t1
    (`c1`)
VALUES
    (1),
    (2),
    (3),
    (4),
    (5)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select count(case when c1 > 2 then 1 else null end) as nb_count from t1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ef866/2/0)**:

```
| nb_count |
|----------|
|        3 |
```

Comment: *ELSE NULL* Skipping ELSE at all will give the same result.

Comment: @Akina yes, even a simple MySQL `IF()` could work, but it's better with the explanation I think ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an EXAMPLE of what your current query is giving you without `COUNT`:

```
SELECT
        CASE WHEN DATE(igs.start_date) >= DATE('2020-05-01') 
        AND DATE(igs.start_date) <= DATE('2020-05- 
        31') THEN igs.id ELSE 0
        END
    AS totalSessions
    FROM
    `ignite_session` igs;

+---------------+
| totalSessions |
+---------------+
| 0             |
| 0             |
| 0             |
| 0             |
+---------------+
*4 row(s) returned.
```

So with `COUNT`, it founded rows being returned thats why you get something in your `totalSessions` even if you didn't any data for that date range. But with a minor change to your query, you can get the correct result. Instead of `COUNT`, use `SUM`. Like this example:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATE(igs.start_date) >= DATE('2020-05-01') AND DATE(igs.start_date) <= DATE('2020-05- 
    31') THEN 1 -- change to 1 instead of igs.id
        ELSE 0
    END)
AS totalSessions
FROM
`ignite_session` igs;
```

Or a much shorter version (similar to Akina's suggestion in the comment):

```
SELECT SUM(DATE(igs.start_date) >= '2020-06-01' AND DATE(igs.start_date) <= '2020-05-31')
 FROM ignite_session igs;
```

[Here's a demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2ekeNe1C9U47XHGBVBCzpp/1) .